# Azure Data Factory V2 - Sending Custom Email (without Logic Apps)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I know that you can send email alerts for a Data Factory pipeline using Azure Monitoring AND that you can send custom emails using a Logic App and the http request trigger.  Is there another simpler way to send an email to alert someone when a pipeline fails with the details of the error message included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but this method would be complex than creating a logic app or configuring default email alerts

1. You can create a stored procedure in a SQL DB which would send an email
2. Add the stored procedure in Failure output section of your ADF activity

Any reason for skipping traditional method of sending email from Azure? Maybe I can help

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of sending emails but I would suggest to use logic apps as the easiest.

You can even run a C# code using custom activity in ADF but it has to be build and deployed to a container and then you have to point this util/exe file in Data Factory -> [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-custom-activity][1]